paypal subscription payment doesnt open on django
I am trying to make a subscription using django and paypal payment. I'm trying to complete a course.
I have made my plans in business sandbox. I've used the code it gives you after making plans and turn them on. I simply copied and pasted the code into my page. It is a local server.
When I click on Paypal buttons they open a blank page. I checked my Inspect and it shows these each time I click on links.
First error:
create_order_error 
Object { err: 'Create Subscription Api response error:\n\n{\n    "name": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",\n    "message": "The specified resource does not exist.",\n    "debug_id": "f913475242396",\n    "details": [\n        {\n            "issue": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",\n            "description": "Requested resource ID was not found."\n        }\n    ],\n    "links": [\n        {\n            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",\n            "rel": "information_link",\n            "method": "GET"\n        }\n    ]\n}', timestamp: "1717846131222", referer: "www.sandbox.paypal.com", sdkCorrelationID: "0b604ba725142", sessionID: "uid_ffb7a1abe3_mte6mjc6mjk", clientID: "AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R", env: "sandbox", buttonSessionID: "uid_ef868db584_mte6mjg6ndg", buttonCorrelationID: "f3594475ad16f", token: null }

Second error:

Uncaught Error: Create Subscription Api response error:

{
    "name": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "The specified resource does not exist.",
    "debug_id": "f693155709fe0",
    "details": [
        {
            "issue": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
            "description": "Requested resource ID was not found."
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
            "rel": "information_link",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}

Last one is a warning:
click_initiate_payment_reject 
Object { err: 'Create Subscription Api response error:\n\n{\n    "name": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",\n    "message": "The specified resource does not exist.",\n    "debug_id": "f693155709fe0",\n    "details": [\n        {\n            "issue": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",\n            "description": "Requested resource ID was not found."\n        }\n    ],\n    "links": [\n        {\n            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",\n            "rel": "information_link",\n            "method": "GET"\n        }\n    ]\n}\nwindow.spb</ne/<@https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.label=subscribe&style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&style.menuPlacement=below&allowBillingPayments=true&applePaySupport=false&buttonSessionID=uid_5e90dddfde_mte6mzi6mzk&buttonSize=huge&customerId=&clientID=AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R&clientMetadataID=uid_ffb7a1abe3_mte6mjc6mjk&commit=true&components.0=…', timestamp: "1717846381227", referer: "www.sandbox.paypal.com", sdkCorrelationID: "0b604ba725142", sessionID: "uid_ffb7a1abe3_mte6mjc6mjk", clientID: "AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R", env: "sandbox", buttonSessionID: "uid_5e90dddfde_mte6mzi6mzk", buttonCorrelationID: "f332954730109", token: null }

I have added this line to my settings.py.
SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY = 'same-origin-allow-popups'
Weird thing is before and after adding this line result was the same.
before adding this when I click on buttons, they open a blank page and it closes after a second.
after adding this line I restarted my server and reloaded the page but everything is the same.
I have checked my account is my sandbox mode. also I am using VPN because the paypal doesnt load without it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Well, I found the problem. The Paypal didnt put my client-id in the button's links, I should have done it myself.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
